# HTML/CSS - Get child iframe to use width of parent container (Twitter widget)

Tags: html, css, iframe, twitter, widget

I've used the [twitter widget](https://twitter.com/settings/widgets) before to embed a twitter timeline. You are given the option to set the height of the widget, and the width has always just expanded to the width of the parent div. However in the current case it is not expanding. Can anyone use a browser web inspector (firebug, etc.) to detect why this particular iframe is getting it's width set to 220px instead of expanding to it's parent div width?

http://m.qwiet.com/ (click "Tweets") once the page has loaded.

Here's the HTML I'm using to embed the timeline:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/user" data-widget-id="248169276782018560">Tweets by @user</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Notice there is no mention of a width parameter. This has been killing me for days now.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean there is no width parameter? Look at the code. It clearly shows `width-"220px"` and when you change it the width changes.

Comment: Yes, but if you look at the HTML I posted above, you will see that I don't specify the width. That 220px is coming from the iframe script that I don't have control over. Other times I've done this the width has been 480px for example, if the containing div has a width of 480px. In this case the containing div has a width of 100%.

Comment: Okay, so what have you tried? Have you even read the documentation?

Comment: Yep. From the documentation: "by default the widget will shrink to the width of its parent element in the page. For example, if you paste your embed code in a div that is 300px wide, the timeline itself will be 300px wide".

Comment: Have you tried making the parent div have a numeric value in pixels instead of 100%? The documentation clearly states that you can only use pixel values for the width of the widget..... Or you could always set the width yourself by adding in the code.

Comment: Yeah I've been messing with that. If I set it to 280px it looks decent on a device, in portrait mode. But if you turn to landscape it stays 280px obviously and only fills half the screen horizontally, so it would be nice to set the parent container's width to some percentage. But I guess I have to live with it.

Comment: You could use javascript to dynamically find the width of the window on the user's browser and then set the width of that to some percentage of that. That would allow you keep the percentage idea, but provide a pixel value for the twitter feed.